# unable to parse the xml query using Linq

Tags: windows-phone-7, linq-to-xml, twitter

I am developing a sample Twitter app for Windows phone 7. In my code to display some details of user, used the following code.

```
    void ShowProfile()
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(Profile_DownloadCompleted);
        client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.xml?user_id=" + this.id));
    }

    void Profile_DownloadCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
        { return; }
        if (e.Result == null) MessageBox.Show("NUlllllllllll");
        XElement Profile = XElement.Parse(e.Result);

    var ProfileDetails = (from profile in Profile.Descendants("user")
                             select  new UserProfile
                             {
                                 UserName = profile.Element("screen_name").Value,
                                 ImageSource = profile.Element("profile_image_url").Value,
                                 Location = profile.Element("location").Value,
                                 TweetsCount = profile.Element("statuses_count").Value,
                             }).FirstOrDefault();

        LayoutRoot.DataContext = ProfileDetails;
 }
```

Here, LayoutRoot is the Grid name. But the data binding doesn't work. 
Infact, when kept a Break point it seems there is no data in the ProfileDetails object. But I could observe that e.Result contains the required data in the XML format.
Can any body figureout where I am going wrong??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used `XElement.Parse` so `Profile` represents the single root `<user>` that API request would have returned.  You are then trying to look for `user` elements inside it which of course makes no sense.

Try `XDocument.Parse` instead.  Also does it really make any sense assigning a `IEnumerable<UserProfile>` to the data context when that list can only ever contain 1 entry?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried XDocument.Parse and it worked.

Comment: Coming to second point you raised, infact that Linq query doesn't return IEnumerable<UserProfile>, returns a single UserProfile object, which the ProfileDetails holds. This is because of FirstOrDefault() method. And ofcourse the response for the web query also returns the details of a single user, not a list. But you cleared my doubt and saved my time. Thanks again.